# Switch case with Checkboxes

Tags: java, checkbox, jframe, switch-statement

I have a switch case statement that is supposed to get the selected index of a combo box and create checkboxes for objects in an ArrayList that the selected index is associated with.

On start up there are no check boxes present, and when a combo box item is selected nothing changes.

```
   int index = showlist.getSelectedIndex();
      switch (index)
      {
         case 1: 
             for(i=0;i<studentlist1.size();i++)
            {
                JCheckBox chbx = new JCheckBox(studentlist1.get(i).getName());
                panel.add(chbx);

                chbx.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        studentlist1.get(i-1).setAbsent();            //causes index out of bounds exception @(i)
                    }
                });
            }
             break;
         case 2:
             for(i=0;i<studentlist2.size();i++)
            {
                JCheckBox chbx = new JCheckBox(studentlist2.get(i).getName());
                panel.add(chbx);

                chbx.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        studentlist2.get(i-1).setAbsent();            
                    }
                });
            }
             break;
        default:
             for(i=0;i<studentlist1.size();i++)
            {
                JCheckBox chbx = new JCheckBox(studentlist1.get(i).getName());
                panel.add(chbx);

                chbx.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        studentlist1.get(i-1).setAbsent();            //causes index out of bounds exception @(i)
                    }
                });
            }
             break;

      }
```

Comment: I see lot of issues with this code. How can you access "i" from anonymous class ? only final variables and memeber variables can be accessed in anonymous class.  Have you forgot to put a break in case 1: ?  with out break it will continue to execute code block in case 2: as well

Comment: Can you specific in your question , I mean what are you are trying to perform with this code and what is not working.

Comment: Im trying to make it so that when a combo box index is selected it provides the relevant checkboxes for the index. currently there are no checkboxes populating the content pane

Comment: I added the break statements, that was a silly mistake, no effect on the outcome though

Comment: I added the default case as well so now boxes show, however, how can i make it so that it refreshes the content pane with the relevant material

Comment: Call `revalidate` and `repaint` on `panel`

Comment: I called it before the break statements but nothing changes